# Node JS - Display a list of users based on their user type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

OK so I need help! I've been stuck on this for a week now and I have no clue what to do!
So basically in my app I'm trying to display a list of users based on their user type. (eg. student, teacher etc.) I can display all the users but not by the specific user type.

Here is an extract of my code for the route to the teacher list.

```
//route for teacher list
router.get('/teacherlist',function (req,res,next) {
    User.find(function(err, teachers) {
        res.render('user/userList', {title: 'user list',teachers:teachers}); 
    });
});
```

teacherlist is where I want to direct the page and that works no problem, its the user.find line that I think I'm going wrong. I know I have declare that I want to display the usertype = teacher, I just am not sure how to do that.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to retrieve users of type `teacher` or `student`, you can try the following:

```
router.get('/teacherlist',function (req,res,next) {
    User.find({ $or: [ { usertype: 'teacher' }, { usertype: 'student' } ] }, function(err, teachers) {
       if(err) {
          next(err);
       } else {
          res.render('user/userList', {title: 'user list',teachers:teachers}); 
       }
    });
});
```

And if you want just a particular user type you could use `@Marco`'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Moongoose for database access?

Here is how you find documents: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

```
//route for teacher list
router.get('/teacherlist',function (req,res,next) {
    User.find({usertype: 'teacher'}, function(err, teachers) {
       if(err) {
          next(err); //pass your error to error handler
       } else {
          res.render('user/userList', {title: 'user list',teachers:teachers}); 
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry yes i am. mLab to be specific.